# WCF Service for Windows Mobile App running but I cannot connect

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-mobile

This is my first attempt at using WCF as well as my first Windows Mobile App. I have been following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004(v=vs.90).aspx

I have created a WCF service, the WCF Service host dialog box pops up and says the service is started with no errors. Yet when I try to navigate to it through my browser it does not work. Everything I am using is on my local machine which is running Windows 7.

I have disabled all firewalls.

I am at a loss here, it says it is started yet I cannot navigate to it. I get an http 400 error when I try.

The metadata address is http://myip:8731/ElectricReadingCacheSyncService

Here is my config code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service name="MiddleTierServiceLibrary.ElectricReadingCacheSyncService" behaviorConfiguration="MiddleTierServiceLibrary.ElectricReadingCacheSyncServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://MYIP:8731/ElectricReadingCacheSyncService/"   />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint 
            address=""  
            binding="basicHttpBinding"  
            contract="MiddleTierServiceLibrary.IElectricReadingCacheSyncContract">
          <identity>
            <dns value="MYIP"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
     </service>
   </services>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MiddleTierServiceLibrary.ElectricReadingCacheSyncServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetai! lInFault s="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the client config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IElectricReadingCacheSyncContract"
                    closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                    sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://MYIP:8731/ElectricReadingCacheSyncService/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IElectricReadingCacheSyncContract"
                contract="IElectricReadingCacheSyncContract" name="BasicHttpBinding_IElectricReadingCacheSyncContract" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What does your **client-side** config look like?? This is the server side - and it appears to be OK as far as I can tell. You're using `basicHttpBinding` - so it's a SOAP service - is that what you're aiming for?? But what does your client config say? Are you using the right address, the right binding??

Comment: As a **SOAP** service, you cannot just navigate to the service in your browser and expect a result on screen. You either need to change the service to be a **REST** based service (`webHttpBinding`) do to that - or use a SOAP tool like the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to see and test your service

Comment: @marc_s: This is actually not completely true. You can view the service definition (assuming proper configuration), by navigating to the service in the browser and adding ?wsdl. You will actually see a link to the ?wsdl page if you navigate to the .svc without any parameters. We often do this as a first troubleshooting step to ensure IIS and the WCF service are configured correctly.

Comment: You may find adding service logging on your server helps: I've a little blog post on that here: http://www.morestuffabout.net/2011/12/debugging-wcf/.

Comment: @competent_tech: yes - sure - you can view the WSDL - but you **cannot** actually test the SOAP service from the browser, e.g. you cannot test/check to see if it's really returning proper results

Comment: @marc_s: Absolutely agree. I had thought your were commenting on the OPs issue of not being able to connect to the service at all, in which case the first step should be to ensure that it is exposed by IIS by navigating to it through the browser. I have seen plenty of cases where .Net framework was added after IIS, leaving the .svc extension unusable and this is a quick test to let you know that part is ok. I think that this approach will also tell you if there is a structural problem with the service (i.e. a class can't be serialized for a response), which is another common problem.

Comment: So there is a lot of discussion here but I see little that actually helps me. Like you said I am not trying to test it I just want to browse to it to confirm it is exposed by IIS. I am actually trying to add it as a web reference and it cannot be found to be added. No web services are found on my local machine and I cannot browse to it. Even though it is started and viewable in the WCF Test Client.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee I used the trace logging and came up with this error: The message with To 'http://myip:8731/NorthwindCacheSyncService/mex/mex' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree. The /mex/mex seems to be the problem but nowhere do I specify that connection. Why is it adding the /mex?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a base address to the configuration:

...
add baseAddress="http://MYIP:8731/ElectricReadingCacheSyncService/"/>'
...

For the data exchange, you're adding "mex":

The mex gets appended to your base address. On your browser, go to:

http://MYIP:8731/ElectricReadingCacheSyncService/**mex**

and you should see the results.

Comment: I understand. I'm pointing out that because of that, he needs to include "mex" to the url.

Comment: I was aware of this and it is not the problem.